# Save custom customer attribute value in observer programmatically | Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, customer, custom-attributes, customer-attribute

I can save custom customer attribute value by frontend controller as:

```
protected $customer;

protected $customerFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
)
{
    $this->customer = $customer;
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

...
...
        $customerId = 1;
        $customer = $this->customer->load($customerId);
        $data = "customer attribute4 value";
        $customerData = $customer->getDataModel();
        $customerData->setCustomAttribute('customer_code',$data);
        $customer->updateData($customerData);
        $customerResource = $this->customerFactory->create();
        //print_r($customerResource);exit;
        $customerResource->saveAttribute($customer, 'customer_code');echo "saved";exit;
```

But with same, value is not getting saved from observer class. No Value is showing in customer grid as well as in Db table.

I am using observer

```
<event name="sales_order_save_after">
```

Also I tried to save value from helper class same issue is from there! Please share the right way to save value.